# Javascript variable doesn't seem to enter the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<head>
<script>
function setParams() {
    var year = "2011";
}

function showYear() {
    alert("The year is " + year);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="setParams();" value="Set" />
<input type="submit" onclick="showYear();" value="Year" />
</body>
```

So why does year not enter the dom for alert to read?

Comment: It posts back the page when you click a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var year = "2011";
```

means the scope of year is local to the function it is declared in

declare it outside the functions. Or remove the var keyword, which also makes it global.

Comment: knew it would be something that simple!  but when I searched google for global js variable, i read stuff saying they didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable declaration:

```
var year = "2011";
```

is a local variable that is only visible inside the function you've declared it in.

If you want it visible globally so other functions can access it, then you must declared it as a global variable where you declare it at the top level of scope outside of any functions:

```
var year;

function setParams() {
    year = "2011";
}

function showYear() {
    alert("The year is " + year);
}
```

A variable declared within a function is, by definition, a local variable and is only available within that function.

Then, lastly you may not quite understand what the DOM is.   DOM standards for "Document Object Model" and the term is used to represent the objects in a web page.  What you are asking about here is javascript global variable syntax which is separate from the DOM.

Hopefully this won't confuse you, but for the sake of completeness of answer, the one place that global Javascript variables and the DOM may appear to be connected is that in a web browser, global variables are also available on the "window" object.  So, in my code example above, you access year as:

```
function showYear() {
    alert("The year is " + year);
}
```

or as:

```
function showYear() {
    alert("The year is " + window.year);
}
```

Both give the same result in a web browser if `year` is a global variable.

Comment: Bugger, you got there just as I was typing. :(

Answer (score 2):

Your year-var will need a global scope so you can can access it in other functions, i.e. you define it outside of the functions. Sth like:

```
var year;

function setParams() {
    year = "2011";
}

function showYear() {
    alert("The year is " + year);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Year is scoped to the function setParams and won't be accessible outside of that function.

You could change the function to

```
function setParams() {
 year = "2011";
}
```

which would give global access to the year variable

**Not necessarily best practise though**

Take a look at the module pattern by Douglas Crockford for a useful way to manage global variables and functions:

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern

Comment: Could you explain how this is supposed to work? This: http://jsfiddle.net/hPxsx/ says "bar is not defined".

Comment: Implicitly declared globals are definitely not a good practice as they are very easy to unintentionally create bugs with.  I would never recommend them.

Comment: @m90 in your jsfiddle, you haven't called the foo function... http://jsfiddle.net/kdkyd/

Comment: @Paul: Ok, didn't know that practice (reads: you ruined me), but now I "get" it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @jfriend00 I would probably argue that pretty much any globally accessible variable is pretty much bad practise and should be avoided - Implicit or explicit.

Comment: @Paul - there are good and legitimate reasons for global variables and there are safe ways to name scope them under a global object.  I consider globals generally a last resort, but still find them the right solution occasionally.  I never use implicit globals though as that's just a bomb waiting to go off.

Comment: @Jfriend00 fair point... m90 there is a good explanation of the module pattern which gives you a good way to manage globally accessible variables and functions which can help avoid overwriting / reusing things you never meant to in your js... well worth implementing if your script / app is anything non trivial: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/